# Query File paths field from Microsoft Defender

Tags: microsoft365-defender

I am looking for documentation on how to build a Advanced Hunting query in Microsoft Defender for Endpoint where I can use the "File paths" in the KQL query.

The field is in the *Software Inventory* under devices and in the section *Software Evidence*
See below screen dump:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO9wJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for one of the pages under the [Data Tables schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender/advanced-hunting-schema-tables?view=o365-worldwide).

My first guess would have been DeviceTvmSoftwareInventory, however that does not seem to include the path.

There are other tables which contain path:
DeviceFileEvents and DeviceImageLoadEvents could be the ones you are looking for, depending on the use case you are trying. The following queries could be a good start.

```
DeviceFileEvents
| where FolderPath contains "part\\of\\your\\path\\comes\\here"
```

or

```
DeviceImageLoadEvents
| where FolderPath == "your\\full\\path\\comes\\here"
```

If you have the full path of every software you are looking for, you can also use FolderPath == the escaped(double `\\` in the path).